# Fedora firewalld issues with docker

Tags: fedora, docker, firewalld

I'm running a service inside docker listening on port 8081. I can access this service on the fedora server itself, but anything else on the network gets a timeout. If I turn off firewalld, the issue resolves itself.

I've added the following XML service to the main network interface on the fedora box as well as adding the docker0 interface to the 'trusted' zone with no luck

XML service I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>My test service</short>
  <description>Custom service</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="8081"/>
  <port protocol="udp" port="8081"/>
</service>
```

Networking has always been my weakest point of knowledge, so sorry if this is a (hopefully though) simple question.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve created a new service definition, but haven’t added it to your firewall configuration. That won’t do you any good. Instead of doing all of that, just use the administration interface instead.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port="8081/tcp" --add-port="8081/udp"
```

Now this does nothing right away. The permanent flag means it’s written to permanent configuration but hasn’t been applied to the runtime configuration yet. You also need to [reload the firewall’s runtime configuration](https://ctrl.blog/entry/firewallctl-reload) from your permanent configuration:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

That is everything you need to do.

Answer (score -3):

Have you made sure that you have also disabled the firewall? if you don't it shall keep turning itself back on.

run: `systemctl disable firewalld`

Comment: I can do that, but really I don't want the firewall disabled. I disabled it to verify that was the problem. I'd prefer to make any necessary adjustments to it to allow the service to communicate on the network while keeping the firewall turned on.

Comment: Oh, have you tried `$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload` the --permanent tag ensures that the change persists across reboots.

Comment: I have. And as far as I know, the XML above added as a service (`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=custom --permanent`) should effectively do the same thing. But no dice.

Comment: can you share the output of `sudo firewall-cmd --list-ports` && `sudo firewall-cmd --list-services` as well as any errors firewalld | docker are throwing as reported by auditd or journalctl -u firewalld|docker ?